# How to repeatedly yank whole buffer without losing the yanked contents

Tags: cut-copy-paste

1. I select the whole contents of a source buffer: `ggVGy`.
2. Then I move to another buffer, let's say `D1`.
3. I update the the whole contents of the destination buffer with the yanked text: `ggVGp`.

Now, if I try to repeat the last two steps on a new destination buffer, let's say `D2`, I see I have lost the original source text. Instead, what I have in the clipboard are the contents of the last destination buffer, `D1`.

- Is there a way I can repeatedly yank the same source text to different destination buffers?
- What can be the reason to this behaviour? May I have a setting saying something like "selecting text automatically yanks it"? If so, I think I would like to disable that behaviour.

Comment: This is a frequent source of confusion :) I wish we had a better reference Q, but romainl's answer below covers most of the important parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can be the reason to this behaviour?

The rationale is explained under `:help v_p`:

```
With p the previously selected text is put in the unnamed register (and
possibly the selection and/or clipboard).  This is useful if you want to put
that text somewhere else.  But you cannot repeat the same change.
```

> Is there a way I can repeatedly yank the same source text to different destination buffers?

Look no further than the next paragraph of the same help section, which gives you two methods:

```
With P the unnamed register is not changed (and neither the selection or
clipboard), you can repeat the same change. But the deleted text cannot be
used.
```

and:

```
If you do need it you can use p with another register.  E.g., yank
the text to copy, Visually select the text to replace and use "0p .  You can
repeat this as many times as you like, and the unnamed register will be
changed each time.
```

So, you would do it like this with the first method:

```
ggVGy
:bnext
ggVGP
:bnext
ggVGP
```

and like this with the second method:

```
ggVGy
:bnext
ggVG"0p
:bnext
ggVG"0p
```

Note that you can use yet another vanilla method: yanking to/putting from a named register:

```
ggVG"ay
:bnext
ggVG"ap
:bnext
ggVG"ap
```

See `:help registers` for `"a` and `"0`.

Comment: You know this, but `:%yank`/`:%yank a` and `:%delete | put 0`/`:%delete | put a` are also options with convenient shorthands.

Comment: Yes I do, and there are other methods, even. But I wanted to stay within the scope of the question.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation. Appreciated!